# How to verify a paid app has not been refunded

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I added a paid app to the Google Play Store a few weeks ago. Over 2/3 of the purchases are refunded within an hour after payment, reason: user requested a refund.

I see the number of users and the country in the Play Console, so it seems those refunded are still using the app after the refund.

Is there a possibility to check in my code if the app has been paid (as it is not an in-app purchase I don't get a token, purchase ID, etc)? I can't find anything in the Android docs.

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing

Comment: @Robert thank you! This looks like a possible solution!